# winsock and x64 target

Tags: winsock

I am trying to build a C based application in 64 bit using the x64 target in the configuration manager in visual studio 2008.

However, I am using sockets and my program includes winsock.h and winsock32.lib in the library section of the project properties?

What is the equivalent for 64 bit? I do not want to run as 32 bit but as a pure 64 bit application.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Subbu

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Microsoft doesn't name some of these libraries very well, I'm afraid.  As long as you link against the 64-bit version of `winsock32.lib` you should be fine.  Here's an [MSDN link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/ee3df896-1d33-451b-a8a3-716294b44b2b/) with a similar problem and more information.

Comment: (Nitpick) It's not Microsoft's fault how the libraries are named. If anyone is to be blamed, it's programmers. They had to keep the same names for backwards-compatibility reasons, or you'd see hundreds of questions on here about that. "Why doesn't my program work anymore when I recompile for 64-bit? Stupid Microsoft, they always break everything."

Comment: @Cody Gray, that's mostly reasonable, except for when the library got named with a 32 in it in the first place.  I'm all for backwards compatibility, but thinking about that a little bit ahead of time can often make a big difference.

Comment: So, for use this http://cs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/practical/CSockets/practical/ I have to link the ws2_32.dll instead of winsock32.lib?

Comment: The name "Win32" was created to distinguish between 16-bit Windows (aka Windows 3.1) and 32-bit Windows (aka Windows 95 et al). 64-bit Windows has been unofficially called "Win64" in a lot of places even on MSDN/TechNet, but there's really no brand "Win64". Windows 64-bit and even Windows RT (aka Windows on ARM) still have "Win32" APIs. Today "Win32" means Win32 desktop apps that run on x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit).

Comment: BTW, "WinRT" means Windows Store apps, Windows phone 8 apps, and Xbox One apps that run on x86 (32-bit), x64 (64-bit), or ARM. It doesn't help that again "WinRT" has been used in places to try to indicate "Windows RT" the operating system.

Comment: Yes this "naming issue" is a compatibility trick for 64 bit Windows installs.
64 bit DLL runtime location:
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WS2_32.dll
32 bit DLL runtime location:
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WS2_32.dll

Answer (score 0):

In my 'Additional Dependencies' I had to change the path:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Lib\winhttp.lib

to:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Lib\ **x64** \winhttp.lib

Comment: Ideally you would not have full paths in your "Additional Dependencies" lists. You should just have "winhttp.lib" listed and the proper LIB path setup for 32-bit vs. 64-bit would link to the correct version.